# ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE issue with Keira3

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, azerothcore

I'm having an issue connecting to the SQL database using the program [Keira3](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) (version `3.0.2`).

> Error:    Client does not support authentication protocol requested by
> server; consider upgrading MySQL client
> Code: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE Errno:   1251 SQL State: 08004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the mysql library used by Keira3 does not support the new Mysql 8.0  authentication protocol, to change it you can run:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1507) for this problem.